# How to get and update a particular object in a deep nested object in mongdb without knowing its depth

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

how do I get the file details nested in an array object's third or fourth level?
The document would get nested deeper as the folder structure goes. How do I get the single file with the id?
here is a sample object: how do i get or update the file details in the last level

```
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6368b3041bbaad24741c5e9e"
  },
  "folderName": "new folder",
  "folders": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6368b3181bbaad24741c5ea0"
      },
      "folderName": "new sub folder",
      "folders": [
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "636a2e9a24ebee4bee48cd23"
          },
          "folderName": "new sub folder2",
          "folders": [],
          "files": [
            {
              "_id": {
                "$oid": "636a2f2624ebee4bee48cd24"
              },
              "folderName": "new sub folder2",
              "fileName": "test doc",
              "title": "title 2",
              "createdby": "maha",
              "status": "draft",
              "content": "<p>This is a sample document inside a sub folder</p>"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "files": [
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "6368b443926f6cdade511159"
          },
          "folderName": "new sub folder",
          "fileName": "test doc 1",
          "title": "title 1",
          "createdby": "maha",
          "status": "draft",
          "content": "<p>This is a sample document inside a sub folder</p>"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "files": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6369f117ac08b48033788b2e"
      },
      "folderName": "new folder",
      "fileName": "test doc 1",
      "title": "title 2",
      "createdby": "maha",
      "status": "draft",
      "content": "<p>This is a sample <strong>doc 1</strong></p>"
    }
  ]
}
```